# buttons are not triggering inside a Bootstrap popover

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I am clicking on a button to trigger an event, but it is not working.... not sure what is causing it..

```
<div class="popOverProgressInsideRightDiv">
        <button id="popOverPause" class="btn btn-mini btn-gray btn-right">Pause</button>
    </div>


render : function() {
var compiledTemplate = Handlebars.compile(aTemplate);

$('#popOverPause').on('click', this.handlePausePress);

this.delegateEvents();

},
handlePausePress : function(event) {
alert("here");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't provide enough information but looks like your `button` is not available in the `DOM` during the page load and being inserted dynamically at a certain point and in this case you need a delegated event handler like

```
$(document).on('click', '.popOverProgressInsideRightDiv #popOverPause', this.handlePausePress);
```

This is just a guess, so not sure whether it's going to work or not, may be you need to post more code and describe broadly.

Take a look at `Direct and delegated events` section in [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/).